# Locking down Ubuntu

Tags: antimalware, defense, ubuntu, virus-removal

A competition is coming up at my school for securing computers and my OS for this challenge is Ubuntu. I'm trying to think of things to add to my list of security measures and things to look out for. Mainly, potential malware. Is there anything besides basic stuff (eg. Password change) that I should look out for/do to ensure maximum security? Also are there any free programs I can use to find viruses or certain types of files that could potentially be dangerous and where might I find them?

(In case you needed to know asking for help is allowed as long as I'm not using it during competition, and even after it ends, I can still use any help for the next competition)

Comment: I don't know the exact Scenario, but most the times its that I'm hired by a company and have to make sure the computer/network is safe.There can be anything from unneeded files (eg. Videos) to users with admin rights to almost anything that can affect security (updating, password protection, etc.). I am given admin rights and can become root. Also by programs I mean basic software I can use via the 'apt-get install' command (eg.rkhunter)

Comment: I misunderstood you. I thought you had to prepare *for* a challenge. Sorry, it's late...

Answer (score 1):

From your description, this competition sounds very similar to [CyberPatriot](https://www.uscyberpatriot.org/) or some derivative of it. To provide context for those who haven't heard of it, this is a style of competition where contestants are provided with virtual machines that are deliberately riddled with vulnerabilities, and are awarded points for fixing them.

Listing all of the possible vulnerabilities that may be present in these machines is (quite literally) impossible. In a way this is reflective of how things work in the real world: once a machine is compromised it is extremely difficult to ensure that it is safe again without a complete OS reinstall. Trying to remove all backdoors that may have been planted is a rather futile endeavor that one should probably not attempt in reality, but I digress...

With this disclaimer out of the way, I can provide a basic list of things these competitions often want you to fix:

- Look through the `/etc/passwd` file to search for any unauthorized accounts that may be present on the system. Lots of these may be legitimate system accounts, so you might have to compare against a copy of the file from a clean system.
- Verify that `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` have correct permissions (664 and 640)
- Install OS updates using `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Ensure that the software update sources haven't been tampered with or disabled.
- Use `ufw` to enable and configure the firewall. Block all inbound connections except on ports that need to remain listening.
- Manually change all user passwords. Also recommend setting a password complexity policy.
- Look for startup scripts and scheduled tasks ([cron jobs](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-show-what-cron-jobs-are-setup/)) that may be launching malicious scripts. Check if there's anything in `/etc/rc.local`.
- Use the `netstat` command to check for network ports the system is listening on. Remove any programs that are listening on ports your machine shouldn't be listening on.
- Search for rootkits with `rkhunter`. You can run a malware scan with `clamav`, but this is rather time consuming.
- If you are required to allow SSH connections, ensure that SSH is secured. In particular, ensure in the SSH configuration that `PermitRootLogin`, `HostBasedAuthentication`, and `PermitEmptyPasswords` options are set to `no`.
- Check every user's home folder for a `.ssh` hidden folder. Remove any entries in the `authorized_keys` file inside, if present.
- Use the `ps` command to list running processes. Check for any obviously named malicious processes.

Again, this is by no means an exhaustive list, and if you are required to keep particular services running (Web server, FTP server, etc.) there will be many things you can do to specifically secure those services. But this should provide a good starting point.

If you aren't sure how to do any of the tasks listed above, you should be able to find more detailed instructions easily via Google.

Comment: In regards to ``/etc/password`` you might also want to check the PAM configuration in ``/etc/pam.d``. Since the system *could* be configured to not use ``/etc/passwd``.